# Installing Yeoman generator globally using npm and Github fork for development

Tags: github, npm, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I currently have quite a few [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io) generators installed globally (e.g., [generator-angular](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular) and [generator-meanjs](https://github.com/meanjs/generator-meanjs)). I'd like to fork one or two and try to contribute back to the community. However, I'm confused as to how I can install and utilize both the forked version as well as the  globally installed generator.

1. Can I install a Yeoman generator globally (e.g., `npm install -g generator-meanjs`) and install a Github fork for development?
2. When developing a forked Yeoman generator, do I need to uninstall the global npm package (e.g., `npm uninstall -g generator-meanjs`) and then follow the [Yeoman Contributing Quick Start instructions](https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/blob/master/contributing.md#quick-start)?

Answer (score 2):

You should clone your fork and then use npm link (from within it) to have it globally available, so that it can be used from yo.

See http://yeoman.io/authoring/ .

Answer (score 1):

Based on my research, the answers are:

1. No. I was not able to find a way to have the Yeoman generator installed globally (e.g., `npm install -g generator-meansjs`) and installed using a local repository containing a clone of the Github fork.
2. No. If the Yeoman generator was previously installed globally, you don't need to uninstall the package prior to linking the local repository. The previously installed package will be replaced with a link to your local repository whenever, you run `npm link <dir>`.

### More Information

I installed [Node](http://nodejs.org) on OS X 10.9.2 using [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) so my global modules are installed at:

```
/Users/matthew/.nvm/v0.10.28/lib/node_modules
```

Then I followed these steps:

```
$ npm install -g generator-meanjs
$ cd ~/.nvm/v0.10.28/lib/node_modules/
$ ls -l generator-meanjs      --> Shows this is a directory
$ cd ~/development/foss-projects/
$ git clone https://github.com/matthewrankin/generator-meanjs
$ cd generator-meanjs
$ npm link .
$ cd ~/.nvm/v0.10.28/lib/node_modules/
$ ls -l generator-meanjs      --> Shows this is a link
```

As can be seen, when I `npm link .` the globally installed package `generator-meanjs` was replaced with a link to `~/development/foss-projects/generator-meanjs`.

Comment: 2. Changing the name in package.json to generator-meanjs-dev allows you to have both installed at the same time. Of course, the original as meanjs and yours as meanjs-dev.